# Making two floating divs match height

Tags: css

I know this has been asked somewhere else, but I can't find the solution.  I have a simple layout.  A container Div with two floating divs inside.  The left div holds the navigation and has a background image.  The right div has a solid background and is dynamic based on the content of each page.  I am not having issues with the content div.  My problem is I want the left div to "stretch" vertically to match the height of the content div.  What is happening is the left is only stretching to the min-height value.  Here is my CSS:

```
#containerTemp {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:1000px;
min-height:100px;
height:auto;
}

#containerNavigation    {
width:210px;
float:left;
background-image:url(../images/template/linkbgd.gif);
background-repeat:repeat-y;
min-height:500px;
height:100%;
}

#containerContent   {
width:790px;
background:#FFFFFF;
background-repeat:repeat-y;
float:right;
min-height:500px;
height:100%;
}
```

You can see the issue by visiting this page: http://www.athensfireandrescue.org/?pid=7

I am sure it's something simple, but I can't put my finger on it.  Sorry for the redundant question, but my searches just didnt' turn up viable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Heights can be a bit tricky. However the goal is to make sure the parent containers have 100% height.You have a lot of stuff going on in your web page. So I created an isolated demo to demonstrate how this works.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {height:100%;}

.wrapper {
    width:400px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.left { 
    width:198px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}
.right {
    width:198px;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/nFdtT/

**SOME OTHER STUFF I NOTICED:**

*If I can offer some advice I would suggest the following:*

1. Don't use tables unless it is tabular data. Your NAV should be constructed using a list.
2. Remove all inline styles and place them in a separate stylesheet.
3. `<meta>` and `<style>` tags should be in the `<head>` of your document. (*For some reason you have a partial doctype heading nested inside of your `<head>`*)
4. And if you aren't already, I would suggest using a CSS reset.

Comment: I took this page over and didn't realize there were any tables still remaining.  Good catch.  Tables removed as well as inline styling.  New problem now :-)  The content of one of my floating divs is flowing past the container div.  Adding a clear class didn't seem to do the trick.  Can you look at the same page again and see if you can see an issue.

Comment: Well one way to fix it would be to set the overflow to auto on `.content {overflow:auto; overflow-x:hidden;}`. However I am not certain that is what you want to do. It really depends on what your design looks like I guess. Also you have a `<meta>` tag and a `<title>` tag inside of your content container. These should both live in the `<head>` of the document.

Comment: Getting there.  Overflow:auto...gives me scroll bars inside the div.  I just want the overall container div (.template) to expand to fit whatever content is in the .content without scroll bars.  the width will never be wider than the content div, but the height will be dynamic depending on the content of each page.

Comment: I just realized what you were saying about the meta and title tags.  I admit I lean heavily on Dreamweaver for coding.  I am a graphic guy trying to play both sides of the website game.  Dreamweaver adds this junk automatically and I didn't catch it.